# How to globally set fontsize in a .tex file

Tags: fonts, fontsize

I tried to use a `.tex` file, which is referenced by many of our LaTeX documents, to globally reduce the font size of some markup that is an {item}.

I tried (in the `.tex` file) which serves as a preamble:

```
\renewcommand\fontsize{small}\selectfont
```

and it had the desired effect of reducing the font size, however it came with a side effect of adding the text "small141.5" a few times before the markup of the actual {item}.

I also tried to use it as `\newcommand` but it had no effect.

The only thing that worked is when I inserted directly into the document, immediately before `\item` (the first line is below)..

```
\fontsize{12pt}\item Let $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{3}{x^2}$.
```

Then the `.tex` file in question does not reference "{item}" at all, so a few questions:

- Is what I'm trying to do possible in a .tex file (so I won't have to a direct insert for possibly thousands of documents?
- Can it be done and not introduce stray characters?

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: What does the referenced `.tex` file contain? Is it simply text to be typeset, with no changes? (For example, if you typeset just that referenced `.tex` file and then pinned those printed pages into the hundreds/thousands of documents, would it work? Not suggesting doing this, just asking so that it's clear to everyone what your task is.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\fontsize` is a core latex command which takes two arguments, a font size and a baselinespacing, if you redefine it you will break almost all latex font change commands.

You could redefine `\normalsize` which in article 10pt option is

```
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xpt\@xiipt
   \abovedisplayskip 10\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus5\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus3\p@
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
   \let\@listi\@listI}
```

which sets the default font to be 10pt and  also sets appropriate defaults for spacing around math and lists.

Comment: Thanks David, but when I added the command you posted, it resulted in an error. I'm not saying the provided suggestion is bad, but in the system in question - I'm new to it and thus not 100% sure of how it works, or if it works correctly at all.

Comment: @AdamT the question is why are you needing to redefine core features  of the system? Especially if you're a beginner (I've been doing this for 30 years and would think twice about redefining things at this level.) if you want a 12pt default just use `\documentclass[12pt]{article}`

Comment: Hi David, the goal I'm trying for is not so much to redefine a core feature of a system, but to make an adjustment of font size that will take place without me having to hand edit hundreds (maybe thousands) of individual documents that "reference" the .tex file.  I've searched in google for examples of how to use a .tex file, but there's not much info I've found. This .tex file is littered with things like \newcommand and \renewcommand

Comment: why can't you use `\large` (which gives 12pt if the default is 10pt, you should almost never need to give numeric values. If you do use numeric values  syntax is `\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\selectfont`  for 12pt font on a 14pt baseline.  You are certainly approaching this the wrong way but it is hard to say what you should do as you haven't given any description of the top level requirement just shown code that will stop latex working.

Comment: I don't think it's a matter of "why can't I do..." the question is "where". If you had 13,000 html pages and on all of them there was code div class="toppy", would it not be easier to adjust all of those references by using a cascading style sheet?  Of course it would. Now I realize I'm comparing HTML/CSS to LaTex. I appreciate your time in trying to help.

Comment: @AdamT yes of course you should almost never need _any_ explicit font commands in the document body the whole point of latex is to separate the main text markup from the document style.  So once you have set up the fonts in the preamble you shouldn't need anything in the document body.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59331/discussion-between-adam-t-and-david-carlisle).